# What software can I use to calculate my private key from a seed (e.g. Trezor or Ledger)?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, backup, mnemonic-seed

I want to make sure I can use my seed from Trezor or Ledger (or others) in a backup process without using an actual Trezor or Ledger to do it.

I have to find out my private key. I probably also need to calculate the addresses I used for receiving bitcoin.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any wallet software that allows restoring from a BIP39 mnemonic will allow you to do that, such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org).

However, you should not do this on your regular computer, since putting your private key on your computer defeats the purpose of having a hardware wallet. If you really have to verify your key is correct, and you'd like to maintain the security of having a hardware wallet, do it from a computer that isn't connected to the Internet.

Comment: or reset the hardware wallet and restore from seed using the device itself.

Comment: "without using an actual Trezor or Ledger to do it." also, restoring the device to test a backup defeats the purpose: if you confident enough that your backup was correct that you'd reset your device, then testing seems redundant, and if not, then you're risking all of your crypto assets just to test the backup that might have never been needed.

Comment: I want to test in general. I want to make sure I know how to use the mnemonic to restore it even if Ledger or Trezor might be out of business or I just don't want to use them any more.

Comment: @Ben Even if Ledger and Trezor go out of business, the physical Ledger and Trezor devices you bought will still work.

Comment: What if I lose them? I had to recover a private key from 2013 in 2020 and it took me a while although this key was not even secured with a password. I had to tinker with it quite a bit to get a working WIF that I could import in a modern wallet. I really need to make sure that there is some very basic way to transfer from a written down mnemonic to a working private key (chain). The chain part is also quite unclear at the moment for me. Everybody storing a mnemonic should think about those things in advance.

Comment: @Ben I would say recovering the older keys might have been more difficult since there wasn't any "industry standard" for it back in 2013 and every program had their own way of doing it, many of which we might not be familiar with today. By contrast, BIP39 is an industry standard, and so is the algorithm for deriving BIP32 hierarchical keys. Any wallet that supports the importing of BIP39 type mnemonics will be recover your mnemonic phrase to your wallet.